# SemanticException [Error 10265] while running simple hive select query on a transactional hive table

Tags: database, hive, hiveql

I created the table in hive:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (COL1 string, COL2 string, COL3 string, COL4 string) CLUSTERED BY(COL2) INTO 4 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC tblproperties("transactional"="true");
```

now trying to query using putty in hive prompt:

```
select * from test_db.test_table;
```

this fails with the below message:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10265]: This command is not allowed
>   on an ACID table test_db.test_table with a non-ACID transaction
>   manager. Failed command: null

Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hive transaction manager must be set to `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager` in order to work with ACID tables.

```
SET hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
```

Additionally, Set these properties to turn on transaction support

**Client Side**

```
SET hive.support.concurrency=true;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

**Server Side (Metastore)**

```
SET hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
SET hive.compactor.worker.threads=1;
```

**Note:** Add these properties in `hive-site.xml` to set them permanently.